# PHP parse <cpe-23:cpe23-item name=" ... ">?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm stuck parsing this label with SimpleXML PHP.

This is my file:

```
<cpe-item name="cpe:/a:%240.99_kindle_books_project:%240.99_kindle_books:6::">
    <cpe-23:cpe23-item name="cpe:2.3:a:\*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"/>
</cpe-item>
```

And I want to parse name content on cpe-23:cpe23-item.

This is my code for now:

```
foreach ($xml->{'cpe-item'} as $cpe) {
  echo $cpe->children('cpe-23', TRUE) // This is the line I have to modify
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$cpe->children('cpe-23', TRUE)` returns all the children in the namespace with prefix `cpe-23:`.

To get to a particular child, the easiest way is to reference it by name, in this case, `->cpe23-item`, since the element is `<cpe23-item ...>`. However, this will confuse PHP's parser, because `-` would normally mean "minus"; you can avoid this using `{}` around the name, like `->{'cpe23-item'}`, with the name itself encapsulated in apostrophes.

To get to an attribute of that element, you would normally use array access, e.g. `['name']`. However, a quirk of XML namespaces means that the `name=` attribute here is in *no namespace*, so you have to use the `->attributes()` function to "leave" the cpe-23 namespace you "entered" with the `->children()` call, giving you `->attributes(null)->name`.

Putting it all together, you have:

```
echo $cpe->children('cpe-23', TRUE)->{'cpe23-item'}->attributes(null)->name;
```